# How to convert integer value to string in Django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to convert something like that id,name to something like that "id","name" in django template.

I looked at django template built in tags but none of them works.

Does anyone have an idea to achieve it?

Comment: If you try to write a CSV file, you should *not* do that through templates.

Comment: No, I just try to auto generate serializer file for django rest framework with some options

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by writing a custom `Template Tag`:

besides your `templates` folder add a directory named `templatetags`.

create `convert_tags.py` in your `templatetags` directory:

```
# convert_tags.py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def add_quotes(value: str):
    """ Add double quotes to a string value """
    return f'"{value}"'
```

In your `templates` load `convert_tags`:

```
<!-- template.html -->
{% load convert_tags %}

{{ your_str|add_quotes }}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand me the id,name is just a string all I need is to add double quotes to them to be like that "id","name"

Comment: The problem that id,name is in one variable not seprated so it's like that I have a variable called fields which equal to id,name

Answer (score 1):

You can simply

```
"{{ id }}", "{{ name }}"
```

Or you can define a custom template tag to do this dynamically

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def quote(str):
    return f'"{str}"'
```

And in your template

```
{{ id | quote }}, {{ name | quote }}
```

Comment: The problem that id,name is in one variable not seprated so it's like that I have a variable called fields which equal to id,name

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everyone,
I solved it by creating a custom template tag

Here's the code :

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

def add_quote(var):
    return '"{0}"'.format(var)

@register.filter()
def add_quotes(value):
    """ Add double quotes to a string value """
    excluded_fields = value.split(',')
    return ",".join(add_quote(i) for i in excluded_fields)
```